# typescript extended / subclass types

Tags: typescript

Trying to do a class with abstract base and the subclases are registered in base class as types. I just want to know if is there an elegant way to type the classes I want.

example:

```js
enum ATypes {
    TYPE1 = 'type1'
}

type SubclassA = any; // This is the type I want to use it.

abstract class A {
    static readonly types: Record<ATypes, SubclassA> | {} = {};
    static readonly type: ATypes;
    static register(cls: SubclassA) {
        this.types[cls.type] = cls;
    }

    public prop1: string;
    constructor(prop1: string) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
    }
}

class Type1A extends A {
    static readonly type = ATypes.TYPE1;
    public prop2: string;

    constructor(prop1: string, prop2: string) {
        super(prop1);
        this.prop2 = prop2;
    }
}

A.register(Type1A);

const AType = A.types[ATypes.TYPE1];
const instance = new AType('prop1', 'prop2');

// new AType(10, 11); // <--- This will fail because are numbers instead strings
```

Comment: Are all the subclasses known ahead of time or is this a library you expect others to extend? What happens if two subclasses try to register with the same enum value for "type"? Given how TS enums are reified, what happens if one registers as "type1" and the other registers as "TYPE1" since both will be in that reified enum object?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mA2j8W) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I lost the constructor checks, but it works.

Comment: What are "the constructor checks"? Could you demonstrate?

Comment: I mean the strict type checks on different subclass constructors but I understand the language limits.

Comment: I'm not understanding; the only thing I did was change `any` to `{ type: ATypes; new(...args: any): A };`, so I cannot even begin to see what sort of checking could be *lost*.  Could you please demonstrate with code in the question what kind of checking you're talking about?  Or are you saying I shouldn't worry about it and just post the answer as-is?

Comment: Just add `const instance = new A.types[ATypes.TYPE1](10, 11);` at the end,and wil notice I can use numbers instead strings additionally says that object could be undefined (added the line to the example code)

Comment: So you want [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/wEpB2W) but this is probably out of scope for the original question as asked.  I'm going to proceed with the original answer if that's okay?

Comment: @jcalz post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a type to represent class constructors with a `types` property of type `ATypes` and which construct instances of `A`, then you can write that simply as

```
type SubclassA = { type: ATypes; new(...args: any): A };
```

which has both a property and a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures).  This will make your original code compile.

However this does not do anything to keep track of which subclasses have been registered.  That is somewhat possible in TypeScript, but it's hard to do it because TypeScript tends to model *static* types.  That is, `A` is the same type before and after you `register()` something.

If you want to try, you can implement `register()` as an [assertion method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) that narrows the type of `this` upon being called.  Assertion functions and methods have lots of weird caveats, but the basic demonstration is as follows:

```
interface AConstructor {
  register<T extends SubclassA>(cls: T): asserts this is
    this & { types: Record<T["type"], T> }
  readonly types: {}
}

abstract class _A {
  static readonly type: ATypes;
  public prop1: string;
  constructor(prop1: string) {
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }
}

const A: AConstructor & typeof _A = Object.assign(_A, {
  types: {},
  register(cls: any) {
    (this.types as any)[cls.type] = cls;
  }
} as AConstructor)
interface A extends _A { }
```

Here we've had to rename `A` out of the way as `_A` and then [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `A` is of the appropriate type where `register` is an assertion method.  If you call `register()` then the type of `this` is narrowed to a version where `types` is known to have a key and value corresponding exactly to the registered subclass.

Now we can try it:

```
enum ATypes {
  TYPE1 = 'type1'
}

class Type1A extends A {
  static readonly type = ATypes.TYPE1;
  public prop2: string;

  constructor(prop1: string, prop2: string) {
    super(prop1);
    this.prop2 = prop2;
  }
}

A.types[ATypes.TYPE1] // error, not registered yet

A.register(Type1A);
const AType = A.types[ATypes.TYPE1]; // okay
const instance = new AType('prop1', 'prop2');
new AType(10, 11); // error, expecting strings
```

I'm not sure I'd really recommend doing this, though.  You'll find that if you change scope, that the compiler might well forget any of your registered classes, because it has no idea that the other scope will be accessed only *after* the registrations take place.  So you'd have to make a copy of your narrowed constructor to "capture" its type and then use the copy in the other scopes.  But then you might as well just make a *builder* instead of mutating an existing thing.  Anyway, these concerns are out of scope for the question as ask, so I won't belabor them.  Suffice it to say that you should test any solution that uses assertion functions thoroughly against your expected use cases before proceeding.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=29&pln=22&pc=1#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-MUgj9nG5JEgsAQyCEjluVRaAFkoF8mg13krUFZnkVnGp8NWXeaAiFwqFIjE4glkiU0jHiJikwAzChCADCLWtxNoVeICZutD6TG4IrFxVrvOW9ywjyYfaKheKgZQ13dpm+xQAZK4-p4hiMxiv-gAiDqvkGzJhLFBRsp1PK+zVo8+D-pyJhZDkeQFC8xQAPqStqZzbIBeyKh0KT8n42q6vqOphhSGLmpa06moSs6koRLY0vOAZXsGhGhuSkZcoOBRkUIKRTvi5E2nOt4dE0I4oIhLgAPLWAAVsMDCdo41BRCAwSIbMUqSPeBAGNM2qLkmu6PPESR0cQwSBsCPgoA4Vm9oCe4WVAYJqBC2rgX+VkSjxM6jIkJjDrcY55oK64gOKomSn+xgmDw-BHJZ6lSHISguJo2i6Dp6wavIhopR0hp6NGJi8igKbBaKoUSnRKEXLsCoHMqcWwOqSVauseGImGxqUtSFrrFafGUXa3VYk6nU0W69LlF6txUeS6aTeZIZqEarGFZIcZ-P8qpNVlihggA9Pt3C0MitCzCATT5HptxQJWrBluxcbXcmaVpji-WNS4G1TFt2HNZqIL+IdKBNAA1mArBFZxmIVCAeZqCAQSNcE6hsuosyo516jpiYiOBMjigAAyzIoih+igwN9AAtDTJVXiggTUFgWAoGOTMoNYwxgLwMCoJEqB8BAnP0GevG7MNMTscV-KGmVG4lAlHoyqhtXAR0X1-VlEa4fCHUogAzJ4gvC-6-W0BRtrURLo0G0b-DCxN9Ket6s2ovN9KLWG+vMXA+urVwblPVAVxLsEMtplFGbGAYQA)